# How does a computer bus physically connect the CPU to multiple different peripheral devices?

Tags: bus

When parallel buses were still used, were they really as simple as just wires being split into however many parallel circuits were need to connect all devices or is there more to the physical implementation?

Comment: Usually, the bus on the backplane or motherboard was just wires. But individual cards might have extra buffers, etc. to limit their loading effects on the bus and transfer the data between their internal logic and the bus. Maintaining signal integrity on such a bus with highly variable configurations of cards is a tricky problem.

Comment: There are different types of [buses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_bus): Address Bus, Data Bus and Control Bus, IO Bus etc. The key concept is that only one (selected) device can write data on the bus. The speed of devices attached to buses varies widely; e.g., memory is super fast and a keyboard is super slow. This means that memory can benefit from an independent bus whereas many I/O devices can share an I/O bus with little difficulty.

Comment: So are the wires that are connecting to the individual devices the same wires for each device?  By that, I mean, let's say n wires that connect to the CPU which form the Control bus are delivering a signal to x number of of devices.  Are each of these n wires split x number of times to form a total of n*x parallel circuits?

Comment: Simplified explanation: First you send out an address on the *same* address bus wires and all devices get to listen to it. The way devices are connected, one of them recognizes that it is being called; rest of them ignore the call. In the next cycle, you can either write to the device or read from the device using control signals such as write/read and the data bus. The same set of wires are re-used in this manner without conflict.

Answer (score 3):

The bus wires can be but don't need to be split to have branches. The bus can just be routed through each component so it is one linear bus, which is often better than splitting/branching the bus in a star topology.

Commonly the devices or chips share data and address bus, and typically peripheral slots also share the control bus, but for example on a motherboard the address bus may have separate address decoding block which will output individual chip select lines for various chips so there is no need to route the whole bus everywhere, just the wires and bits that are necessary.